# How to access fields of nested structs in an array of interface type

Tags: go

I would like to access the FieldBase field within these nested structs.

Here's my code example:

```
type InterfaceA interface {
    FunA()
}

type BaseStruct struct {
    FieldBase string
}

type SubStruct struct {
    BaseStruct
}

func (c SubStruct) FunA() {
}

type SubStruct2 struct {
    BaseStruct
}

func (c SubStruct2) FunA() {
}

func main() {
    var x = [2]InterfaceA{
        SubStruct{BaseStruct: BaseStruct{FieldBase: "aaa"}},
        SubStruct2{BaseStruct: BaseStruct{FieldBase: "bbb"}},
    }

    // TODO: Access fields of nested classes in the array

}
```

I would like to know how to access the FieldBase field value of each nested struct in the array x, where x is of interface type. I attempted to use type assertions for access, but I'm only able to attempt it on a single element.

```
if subStruct, ok := x[1].(SubStruct); ok {
    fmt.Println(subStruct.FieldBase)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Cannot access FieldBase")
}
```

Comment: You have to type assert each element individually to its dynamic type. You can use a type switch to check against one or more types. Alternatively you could use reflection, but that's not recommended.

Comment: Well, don't do that. It's just too painful as you have to type assert everytime. And: arrays are _really_ uncommon in Go. Last: Don't call things Base and Sub. Embedding is not inheritance. Your code doesn't read as if it would be Go code. This is not an answer to your question but your code might benefit from refactoring to "not-unidiomatic".

Comment: As a beginner, it's completely normal to find it challenging to switch to Go and adapt to its coding style, especially coming from other languages. It takes time and practice to become proficient and comfortable with Go's conventions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your array is of an interface, you'd either need to do type assertions and handle for each type or have an interface method. However I think what you intend on and need is to have an interface  method for each struct type that exposes FieldBase as follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type InterfaceA interface {
    FunA()
    GetFieldBase() string
}

type BaseStruct struct {
    FieldBase string
}

type SubStruct struct {
    BaseStruct
}

func (c SubStruct) FunA() {
}

func (c SubStruct) GetFieldBase() string {
    return c.FieldBase
}

type SubStruct2 struct {
    BaseStruct
}

func (c SubStruct2) FunA() {
}

func (c SubStruct2) GetFieldBase() string {
    return c.FieldBase
}

func main() {
    var x = [2]InterfaceA{
        SubStruct{BaseStruct: BaseStruct{FieldBase: "aaa"}},
        SubStruct2{BaseStruct: BaseStruct{FieldBase: "bbb"}},
    }

    // TODO: Access fields of nested classes in the array

    fmt.Println(x[0].GetFieldBase())
    fmt.Println(x[1].GetFieldBase())
}
```